# Breezejs + Angular - How to Properly Map Database Property Names?

Tags: angularjs, select, mapping, breeze, ng-options

I have a working and reusable custom `<select>` directive that populates via `ng-options`, here is the snippet:

```
ng-options="datum.name for datum in data track by datum.id"
```

This works as intended when I use a local test JSON file to populate it as I can define the `name` and `id` properties manually. When using Breezejs (which is properly pulling back data as expected), the database has `Product` and `DeviceID` instead of the desired `name` and `id` properties.

I want to be able to pull the data, but map `Product` and `DeviceID` to `name` and `id` as doing so ensures the goal of reusability of my custom `<select>` directive. Many different entities will need to map to `name` and `id`, so this is important for reusability.

How do I accomplish this? I've looked at [Mapping JSON to entities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mapping-json) and [JsonResultsAdapter](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/JsonResultsAdapter.html) thinking this is the right direction. Unfortunately, these examples seem to be missing what I need (unless I'm missing something).

Are there other solutions or ways to tackle this problem? Is there a best practice way of doing this using breezejs? Thank you in advance for any light you can shed.

---

*Found a solution

I was using a custom directive like so (but I now add the `options-map` attribute):

```
<sel-select-box
        id="selectBoxDevice1"
        select-size="10"
        options-map="datum.Product for datum in data track by datum.DeviceID"
        service-in="deviceSearchDataService"
        service-in-watch="getDevice1Matches"
        service-in-restore="getDevice1Selection"
        service-out="deviceSearchDataService"
        service-out-send="updateDevice1Selection">
</sel-select-box>
```

Then in my reusable `<select>` I reference the `{{optionsMap}}` like so:;

```
<select 
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="selected"
    ng-change="onChange()"
    ng-click="onClick()"
    ng-options="{{optionsMap}}"
    data-ng-attr-size="{{selectSize}}">
</select>
```

As a result I can now use the numerous custom `<sel-select-box>` directives and simply add the proper map string that the `<select>`'s `ng-options` utilizes.

I'm super stoked this works and that it achieves the flexibility I desire, but I'm still open to improved ideas and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at a custom NamingConvention? The NC is dedicated to the business of mapping between client-side and server-side entity property names